# Kotlin: How to iterate all dates within a Joda Interval?

Tags: kotlin, jodatime, intervals

I'd like to iterate all dates within a given Joda interval:

```
val interval = Interval(DateTime.now().minusDays(42), DateTime.now())
```

How to do that in Kotlin?

Comment: "A time interval represents a period of time between two instants. Intervals are inclusive of the start instant and exclusive of the end."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following extension function gives a `Sequence` of `LocalDate` objects from the given `Interval`, which can be used to iterate those dates.

```
fun Interval.toLocalDates(): Sequence<LocalDate> = generateSequence(start) { d ->
    d.plusDays(1).takeIf { it < end }
}.map(DateTime::toLocalDate)
```

Usage:

```
val interval = Interval(DateTime.now().minusDays(42), DateTime.now())
interval.toLocalDates().forEach {
    println(it)
}
```

In this solution, the last day, `DateTime.now()` is not included in the `Sequence` since that's how `Interval` is implemented as well:

> "A time interval represents a period of time between two instants. Intervals are inclusive of the start instant and exclusive of the end."

If, for any reason, you want to make it include the last day, just change the `takeIf` condition to `it <= end`.

Comment: why you need the Interval to create this sequence? I mean, just have that sequence function alone from 2 instances sounds already solved no?

Answer (score 6):

Heavily inspired by your current solution:

```
fun Interval.toDateTimes() = generateSequence(start) { it.plusDays(1) }
                                                 .takeWhile(::contains)
```

Usage:

```
interval.toDateTimes()
        .forEach { println(it) }
```

If you need the `LocalDate` you could still do the following instead:

```
interval.toDateTimes()
        .map(DateTime::toLocalDate)
        .forEach { println(it) }
```

or as an extension function to `Interval` again:

```
fun Interval.toLocalDates() = toDateTimes().map(DateTime::toLocalDate)
```

If you want the end date to be inclusive instead, use `takeWhile { it <= end }` instead.

Comment: Yes, I need `LocalDate`, so the only improvement would maybe be the function reference, which I really prefer, thanks

Comment: adapted it... using `takeWhile` now, which - I think - is even more readable.

Answer (score 4):

I guess if you need it more than once, it would be better to overload rangeTo operator to allow this syntax

```
for (i in LocalDate.now() .. LocalDate.now().plusWeeks(1)) {
    System.out.print(i) // 2018-08-30 2018-08-31 2018-09-01 
}
```

Here is the code for operator extension:

```
operator fun LocalDate.rangeTo(other: LocalDate): LocalDateRange {
    return LocalDateRange(this, other)
}
```

And necessary classes:

```
class LocalDateRange(override val start: LocalDate, override val endInclusive: LocalDate)
    : ClosedRange<LocalDate>, Iterable<LocalDate> {
    override fun iterator(): Iterator<LocalDate> {
        return DateIterator(start, endInclusive)
    }
}

class DateIterator(start: LocalDate, private val endInclusive: LocalDate)
    : Iterator<LocalDate> {

    private var current = start

    override fun hasNext(): Boolean {
        return current <= endInclusive
    }

    override fun next(): LocalDate {
        current = current.plusDays(1)
        return current
    }
}
```

Comment: If you increment the date like that, you'll never get the `start` value from the iterator.  `return current.also { current = current.plusDays(1) }` works better.

Answer (score 4):

`LocalDate` is preferred nowadays, so we can simply iterate with day as number:

```
for (day in minDate.toEpochDay()..maxDate.toEpochDay()) {
    // ...
}
```

or:

```
(minDate.toEpochDay()..maxDate.toEpochDay()).forEach {
    // ...
}
```

Iterate with day as date:

```
generateSequence(minDate) { it.plusDays(1) }.takeWhile { it < maxDate }.forEach {
    // it ...
}
```

or:

```
var day = minDate;
while (day < maxDate) {
    day = day.plusDays(1);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The question is for JodaTime so your first two answers won't work, as `toEpochDay` is only on java.time `LocalDate`. I know we should all be on java.time but some of us are stuck with Joda! Your third answer is the same as the other answers in this thread. But your fourth answer works great and is the simplest solution to Kotlin's lack of a 'traditional' for loop.

Comment: Joda and Local can be perfectly combined and piece by piece moved from Joda to Local. So I would say it's just about preference.